# Sampling from density specified in terms of spacing ratios?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Given a sorted vector of positive reals $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_P\}$ and corresponding vector of spacing ratios $r_i=\frac{\lambda_i-\lambda_{i-1}}{\lambda_{i-1}-\lambda_{i-2}}$, I know that as $P\to \infty$, the density of $r$ approaches the following

$$P(r)=\frac{27 \left(r^2+r\right)}{8 \left(r^2+r+1\right)^{5/2}}$$

How would I get a sample of $\lambda$'s?

```
density = 27 (r + r^2)/(8 (1 + r + r^2)^(5/2));
```

This comes from formula 7 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5611.pdf)

Comment: So, your question is really just how to get a sorted list of reals?

Comment: `Sort[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 20]]` gives you a sorted list of 20 reals randomly selected from the range {0,10}.

Comment: If you know $r_i$, you can determine $\lambda_i$. Just notice that the map is not unique. The ratio is translationally invariant, therefore without loosing generality we can set $\lambda_1=0$. Furthermore, the ratio is scale-invariant. Therefore, we can set $\lambda_2=1$ without loosing generality. Thus, generate random $r_i$ according to your distribution and perform the transform.

Comment: Or is your goal to find the distribution analytically?

Comment: @yarchik my goal was to get CDF of density of $\lambda$ analytically in the $\lambda\to 0$ regime (is it a power-law or something else?). Given the approach taken by the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5611.pdf) I assumed that might be be too hard (since it would let you obtain analytical expression for density of zeros of Riemann zeta function), hence starting with random sampling

Comment: Is there reason to believe that the $R_i$’s are not serially correlated?

Comment: @JimB $r$i's give a distribution that occurs if we take a large collection of numbers, sort them, and look at their spacings. I'm trying to go in the opposite direction, given distribution of spacings, look at kinds of distributions that could've produced it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows @yarchik 's comment.

First, generate a random sample of values from the random variable $R$ with density

```
density = 27 (r + r^2)/(8 (1 + r + r^2)^(5/2));
```

Using the [inverse transform sampling method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) find the cdf of $R$ and set that to a value $U$ from a standard uniform distribution:

```
cdf = (Integrate[density, {r, 0, r0}, Assumptions -> r0 > 0]) /. r0 -> r
(* (-2 - 3 r + 3 r^2 + 2 r^3 + 2 (1 + r + r^2)^(3/2))/(4 (1 + r + r^2)^(3/2)) *)
sol = r /. Solve[cdf == u, r, Reals]
```

[image: Solution to cdf == u solving for r]

It turns out that the 5-th and 6-th roots are what we want when $0<u<1/2$ and $1/2<u<1$, respectively.  Writing a piecewise function for obtaining a random sample from $R$ follows:

```
randomR[uu_] := Piecewise[{{sol[[5, 1]] /. u -> uu, 0 < uu < 1/2}, 
  {sol[[6, 1]] /. u -> uu, 1/2 < uu < 1}, {1, uu == 1/2}, {0, uu == 0}}, ∞]
```

As a partial test of whether this works, take random sample and compare the associated histogram with the density:

```
n = 10000;
SeedRandom[12345];
rr = randomR[#] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
Show[Histogram[rr, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"],
 Plot[density, {r, 0, 10}]]
```

[image: Histogram of data and true density]

**Update 1:**  @kglr in a comment below showed that a random sample can be used with the simpler *Mathematica* code:

```
pd = ProbabilityDistribution[density, {r, 0, Infinity}];
SeedRandom[12345];
rr = RandomVariate[pd, n]
```

Now generate values of $\lambda$.  From the relationship given we have:

```
Solve[ri == (λi - λi1)/(λi1 - λi2), λi][[1, 1, 2]]
(* λi1 + ri λi1 - ri λi2 *)
```

$$\lambda_i=\lambda_{i-1}+r_i (\lambda_{i-1}- \lambda_{i-2})$$

Putting this all together:

```
(* Random sample of R values *)
n = 1000;
SeedRandom[12345];
rr = randomR[#] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];

(* Generate λ values *)
λλ = ConstantArray[0, n];
λλ[[1]] = 0;
λλ[[2]] = 1;
Do[λλ[[i]] = λλ[[i - 1]] + rr[[i]](λλ[[i - 1]] - λλ[[i - 2]]), {i, 3, n}]

(* Plot results *)
ListPlot[λλ, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Italic, 18] &) /@ {"i", "λ[i]"}]
```

[image: Series of lambda values]

I don't know the subject matter so I have no idea if the resulting figure makes any sense or if the cited paper makes any sense or if I've made an error.  All are possible.

**Update 2**:  Finding a nice closed-form formula for the density of $\lambda_i$ does not seem likely as the random variables $\lambda$ become more and more difficult to deal with.  We have for the first few $\lambda$ random variables the following pattern:

$$\lambda_3=1+R_3$$
$$\lambda_4=1+R_3+R_3 R_4$$
$$\lambda_5=1+R_3+R_3 R_4+R_3 R_4 R_5$$
$$\lambda_6=1+R_3+R_3 R_4+R_3 R_4 R_5+R_3 R_4 R_5 R_6$$

@kglr also showed how to produce this using the following:

```
solλ = RSolve[{λ[m] == λ[m - 1] + r[m] (λ[m - 1] - λ[m - 2]), λ[1] == 0, λ[2] == 1},
  λ[m], m][[1]] /. {K[1] -> j, K[2] -> i}
```

[image: Solution for lambda[i]]

The above can be simplified for each value of $m$:

```
solλ /. m -> 3 // Expand
(* {λ[3] -> 1 + r[3]} *)

solλ /. m -> 6 // Expand
(* {λ[6] -> 1 + r[3] + r[3] r[4] + r[3] r[4] r[5] + r[3] r[4] r[5] r[6]}
```

However, one can produce the density for $\lambda_4$ numerically (as opposed to random sampling) by integrating the product of the densities times the Jacobian with `r4` replaced by `(-1 - r3 + \[Lambda]4)/r3` over `r3` ranging from 0 to `\[Lambda]4 - 1`:

```
(* Jacobian *)
J = 1/r3;
(* Integrand *)
integrand = FullSimplify[(density /. r -> r3) (density /. r -> (-1 - r3 + λ)/r3) J, 
  Assumptions -> {r3 > 0 && λ > r3 + 1}];
(* Probability density function *)
pdfλ4[λ4_] := NIntegrate[integrand /. λ -> λ4, {r3, 0, λ4 - 1}]
```

Now to compare with a random sample:

```
n = 10000;
density = 27 (r + r^2)/(8 (1 + r + r^2)^(5/2));
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[density, {r, 0, ∞}];
SeedRandom[12345];
rr3 = RandomVariate[dist, n];
rr4 = RandomVariate[dist, n];
λλ4 = 1 + rr3 + rr3*rr4;

Show[Histogram[λλ4, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"],
 Plot[pdfλ4[t], {t, 1, 20}]]
```

[image: Histogram and density of lambda 4]

Comment: we can simplify the first step using `pd = ProbabilityDistribution[density, {r, 0, Infinity}];
SeedRandom[12345]; rr = RandomVariate[pd, n]`

Comment: @kglr Thanks!  I'll incorporate that.  I foolishly assumed that *Mathematica* wouldn't be able to handle getting random numbers directly from that density.

Comment: @kglr Very good.  I did just find the same result in a brute force manner.  It simplifies to $1+r_3$, $1+r_3+r_3 r_4$, $1+r_3+r_3 r_4+r_3 r_4 r_5$, $1+r_3+r_3 r_4+r_3 r_4 r_5+r_3 r_4 r_5 r_6$, etc.  The mean continues to increase with increasing $m$ and that is the only integer moment that exists:  i.e., the variance doesn't exist even for $m=3$.  And I'm more that a bit skeptical that there's a closed form for the density.

Comment: Nice investigation! The CDF looks a bit suspicious however. One way to get spacings with $P(r)$ close to above is to let lambda be the eigenvalues of a sample from GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[10000], CDF will be a lot less peaked.

Comment: Not that it isn't related but I have no idea how your comment relates to determining the distribution of the $\lambda$'s from the distribution of the spacings.

Comment: @JimB ok, I confirmed that your simulation [appears to work](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-jimb-spacings.nb). The intiguing observation is that wildly different distributions of lambdas result in the same distribution of spacings

Comment: "appears to work." ? In that code you generate a random sample from $R$, convert that to $\lambda$ values and then covert back to values of $R$ (with the exception of along the way dividing the $\lambda$ values by the maximum $\lambda$ value for some reason).  The values of `toSpacings@evals1)[[1 ;;]]` are essentially identical to `rr[[3 ;;]]`.

Comment: @JimB ok looks like this problem is under-determined. To go from distribution of spacings to density you need all $n^2$ pairs of spacings (equation 5 in [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/473/1/012002/pdf)) but here I only give $n$ pairs